# rsync --append or --append-verify flags causing transfer to error on resume

Tags: linux, networking, backup, rsync, sshfs

Trying to do a transfer with rsync using `rsync -rtlv --no-i-r --no-perms --partial --inplace --append-verify /srv/raid /mnt/backup`. I use it in a script to transfer the contents of a server's RAID array to a backup system mounted locally or via SSH.

Normally, this works fine, but if I try force-stopping and resuming the transfer to test what happens if the connection is dropped mid-way, it crashes upon resuming. The **append-verify** option is supposed to allow rsync to resume where it left off (good for transferring very large files, which I have a fair number of), but instead, it causes this weird error. I get the same error using **append** flag as well, and I even get it if I remove **partial** or **inplace**.

I have no idea why the heck this isn't working. But the moment I take off the append flags, rsync works fine, it just deletes and re-starts the file instead of resuming, so workable, but not what I want.

Here is the error in question:

```
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at io.c(823) [sender=3.2.3]
rsync error: received SIGUSR1 (code 19) at main.c(1595) [generator=3.2.3]
```